# Upgrading Intercom SDK leads to a bunch of "Error:(6) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name" errors

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, intercom

I'm absolutely new to the Android development world, so please excuse me if this is a stupid question.

I've inherited a very old Android codebase which is using a deprecated Intercom SDK. I followed the instructions at https://www.intercom.com/help/articles/2723-upgrade-to-the-new-messenger-android and changed the following lines in `build.gradle`...

```
compile('io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk:1.1.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

...to what was suggested in the blog post, i.e:

```
compile ('io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk:3.+')
```

Unfortunately, trying to build the project, now leads to a bunch of the following errors:

```
Error:(6) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(36) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
```

I've trying different variations of the following, but nothing worked:

```
compile ('io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk:3.+@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

Reading answers to similar questions, I realise that this may be related to the SDK version (or some support/compatibility library version), so here are the relevant settings from my gradle file:

```
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.vacationlabs.backoffice'
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 11
    versionName "1.1.1"
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.bartoszlipinski.recyclerviewheader:library:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.roomorama:caldroid:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.1'
    // compile ('io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk:3.+')

//    compile ('io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk:3.+@aar') {
//        transitive = true
//    }
    compile('io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk:1.1.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the dependencies tree using the command `./gradlew app:dependencies`.

Some of your dependencies have a transitive dependency with the support library xx.
You have to compile (at least) with the same version of support library changing

```
compileSdkVersion XX
```